# How to choose the proper PhaseId in JSF?

Tags: jsf

Am running all my Phase Listeners in `RENDER_RESPONSE` phase.

I came across [this post](http://java.dzone.com/tips/jsf-application-level-access) which talks about using `RESTORE_VIEW` phase for Application level access control. So, this gives me a thought that Phase Listeners might have to be run on different `PhaseId` based on the requirement.

Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope) from BalusC, gives a good picture on choosing the right bean scopes.

Similarly, is there an explanation for choosing the right `PhaseId`?

Comment: What do you mean with "applications"?

Comment: By "applications" I mean all my JSF implementations (To be specific its JSF1.2) I have edited my question accordingly

Comment: How exactly are you running them in render response phase? This statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have this piece of code in my `CustomPhaseListener`. `public PhaseId getPhaseId()
  {
    return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
  }` I think, I should have better used the term _listening_ instead of _running_

Comment: So? That just invokes the `beforePhase()` and `afterPhase()` methods of the same phase listener instance during render response phase. How exactly are you running a "JSF application" or "JSF implementation" through it?

Comment: I was still adding this statement, "I think, I should have better used the term _listening_ instead of _running_". Before posting this, I mistakenly pressed Enter button. How to decide at which `Phase` should my JSF implementation should invoke `beforePhase()` and `afterPhase()` ?

Comment: Perhaps you actually meant to say "all my phase listeners" instead of "all my JSF implementations"?

Comment: Exactly. I meant to say "all my Phase Listeners"  :)